# Obj-C - Drag and drop TableViewCell from one TableView to another TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two TableViews inside the same View Controller. I'm trying to make it so that a user can drag a TableViewCell from the first TableView, and drag/drop it into the second TableView next to it. I've been hunting around forever for tutorials/solid examples of how to do this, but there seems to be very little information out there on this topic. It also doesn't help that I'm looking for documentation for Objective-C.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view#see-also

This is the closest thing I've found to information on implementing the Drag & Drop API to a tableview. Does anyone have any useful **Obj-C** tutorials or code that can help me accomplish this task?

I know this isn't a typical question, but I think it would be very useful to a large audience.

Comment: One solution you can try is to use UIDropSession property localDragSession.location(in: self.view), and try to identify which tableview is at that position.

Comment: Why not just create a UITableView with multiple reorderable sections?